# Update dynamic heightmap in Away3d 4.x Broomstick

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, away3d, stage3d

How do I update my Elevation Object when I change the bimapdata of its height map?

I noticed that getHeightAtPosition() updates to the values of the new bitmap, but the Elevation still looks the same..

(I know it is possible to loop through all vertices in the geometry mesh and adjust them based on the bitmap, but the nice thing with Elevation is that you don't have to do that. If it can adjust to the bitmap on creation it should be able to update..)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer on the away 3D forum:
http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/1110/#3808

Basically, you need to change one line in the Elevation class:

Go to elevation.as and change

```
private function updateGeometry()
```

to

```
public function updateGeometry()

then on the render after you change the parameters call
_elevation.updateGeometry();
```